# Migrate LUKS encrypted Linux Mint and Bitlocker encrypted Windows to *same* disk

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, disk-encryption

It's been a while since I installed my LUKS encrypted Linux Mint 19 on a M.2 SSD drive and Windows 10 with BitLocker encryption on a **separate** SATA SSD drive. I used them in dual-boot mode with GRUB and that is working fine.

Now I have a new notebook and want to move the two operating systems to one large M.2 SSD drive. Is that possible without reinstalling?

1. Can I simply clone them to the new disk?
2. In which order will I have to do that?
3. Anything else I have to take care of?

I researched the topic a bit and could only find information about new installations...

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I would strongly recommend suspending BitLocker to achieve your goal

Comment: `dd` should work fine for the LUKS partitions, but I don't know about bitlocker

Comment: I read that it is recommended to install Windows first, and then install Ubuntu to have less problems with the boot loader (the way I initially installed on the two disks). I didn't find information about cloning the two OS to one disk (which would come nearest to what I try to achieve). So you suggest to clone LUKS partition first and then install windows on another partition? I am not very familiar with things like MBR etc.

Comment: I will do as suggested, I `dd` the LUKS partition on the new disk and then reinstall windows [from scratch](https://itsfoss.com/install-windows-after-ubuntu-dual-boot/) as second OS without encryption.